# access Monitored Users

Tags: debugging, logging

I got a simple question, for custom logging I need to lookup some ApexLogs.

Is there a way to access the Monitored Users for debug logging?
I like to create or reset them programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the new [Tooling API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf)
This includes instructions for accessing debug logs etc.

"To diagnose a functional issue or a performance problem, use the TraceFlag object to set up logging for yourself or for another user"
There is also a code snippet on page 45 showing how to set up a log for a user, and specify the various logging levels.
This is available in Summer 13 release.

Comment: Oh that's realy nice, I was looking for this since months. thanks!

Comment: There is some nice stuff in the Summer 13 release. :) Glad this helped you.